# Spd-say does not pronounce the argument

Tags: bash

I've written a script and the first part does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
spd-say "What do you want?"
read a
if [ "$a" == "water" ] || [ "$a" == "Water" ]
then
spd-say "Take the bottle."
else 
spd-say "Sorry, we don't have water, choose something else."
fi

spd-say "Please pay the money."
read b
if [ "$b" == "yes" ] || [ "$b" == "Yes" ]
then
spd-say "Thanks."
else
spd-say "Sorry!"
fi
```

When i execute the code the first part asks the question but regardless of my answer it skips to the second question, while the second part after "Pay the money" works well. I don't know why, but the structure of both parts is the same. Can anyone help?

Comment: I've replaced the `spd-say` with `echo` (so it will print the text to the terminal), and it works fine... (i.e. execute both parts of the script as expected). @Arch - what happened when you execute the script using `echo` instead of `spd-say`?

Comment: It's handy to know that bash parameter expansion can transfer the contents of a variable `$a` to all lower case with`${a,,}` or all upper case with `${a^^}`. This can avoid the need to use `||` to test for capitalisation of the question responses.

Comment: To elaborate on @Arronical's comment: This would be `if [ "${a,,}" == "water" ]; then …`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>For those who don't know (I didn't either): `spd-say` reads a given text aloud (e.g. if you cannot read yourself or like listening instead of reading).</sup>

Your script looks fine but you have fallen in a trap:

`spd-say` doesn't wait until it has spoken the given text. Instead, the command (almost) immediately returns and keeps talking in the background. If you run it a second time without waiting for the first talking to complete (like in your script), then it will simply talk over the first part. To prevent this, use the `-w` (or `--wait`) switch. Then `spd-say` will return only once it has completed talking. See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/spd-say.1.html) for further switches.

So instead of

```
spd-say " Sorry, we don't have water, choose something else."
```

use

```
spd-say --wait " Sorry, we don't have water, choose something else."
```